# How can I update my custom db when a user sign up with google in auth0?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

Whenever a user sign up for the first time using google, auth0 is not updating it to my custom database.

Comment: please provide more information about your question and some code that show  what you did so far ?

Comment: I have created a login application using auth0. Whenever I sign up using email and password, it gets updated to my custom db. But when I am trying to sign up for the first time using my google account, there is no updation in my custom db.

Comment: @DishantKedia While you are signing with the google account, please debug and check that Are you getting the value for the email and password? And Make sure that there is no any exception because it stops the further process of saving fetched data from google account to your db.